# css width and height not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to make an online game. I am trying to model the login screen after Paper.io. I made the username input and play button, but the width and height specified in the css file for the input for the username is not working. It is specified as 216 x 30 but when I open the website it doesn't work. What's weird is that when I put all of the code into a code snippet on this forum, it works fine, but when I run it on my own computer, it doesn't work. This is my first online HTML5 game so please don't yell at me! :(

```css
html,
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
  font-size: 22px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#game .ctx,
#ctx {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#pre_game {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #dff3f7;
}

#pre_game .dark,
#dark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

#pre_game .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 160px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  background: url('/img/logo.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#pre_game .grow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -168px;
  width: 336px;
  top: 250px;
}

#pre_game .grow {
  animation: leaves 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: leaves 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

#pre_game input,
#contact .button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 216px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: #ededd1;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a1a18d;
  outline: none;
}

#contact .button {
  text-indent: 0;
}

#pre_game .button,
#contact .button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
}

#pre_game .button,
#contact .button {
  background: #eaec4b;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a1a130;
  margin-top: -2px;
  color: #888a34;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 34px;
}

#pre_game .button:hover,
#contact .button:hover {
  background: #fafc5b;
}

#pre_game .button:active,
#contact .button:active {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a1a130;
  border-top: 4px solid #333;
}

@keyframes leaves {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes leaves {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}

#pre_game:before {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 320px #80969e;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 320px #80969e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

input:not([type]),
input[type="email" i],
input[type="number" i],
input[type="password" i],
input[type="tel" i],
input[type="url" i],
input[type="text" i] {
  padding: 1px 0px;
}

input {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
  font: 13.3333px Arial;
}

button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

```html
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest Guy' rel='stylesheet'>


<div id="pre_game" style="display: block;">
  <div class="dark"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="grow">
    <div class="username">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" style="left: 0px;">
    </div>
    <div class="button play" style="right: 0px;" onclick="game_start()">PLAY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I don't think that I was clear enough in my explanation above. In the code snippet posted that is how I want it to be, however when I run the EXACT same code on my own computer and ope nthe website, it is not the same. Here are some screenshots showing what I see.
[what I see in the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tq1m.png)
The dimensions in the following picture is what is wrong. they should be 216 x 30 not 206 x 0.
[Wrong dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHR1d.png)

ANSWER: To be honest I don't know why this worked but it did. I tried the normalize.css thing and even added the lines of CSS Timber Hjellum included and that only made it worse. I realized that the numbers I put in for padding on the sides were subtracted from the original width and height and those numbers became the actual width and height of the element. All I did was add 10 to the width (5px padding on left and right is 10 total) and added 36 to the height (15px padding on top and bottom is 30 but when I added 30 it ended up saying a height of 24 so I added 6 more). Anyways Thanks all for your help!

Comment: why do you define twice the #contact .button height and width?'

Comment: spent 10 mins playing paper.io :)

Comment: @Andrei hahaha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should look into is to add a CSS reset or normalize.css into your project (not both). You can Google and grab the latest from github and the benefit is that it makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. This will make your life much happier not having to constantly deal with all of these pixel inconsistencies across different browsers and media devices.

Then consider this box sizing CSS snippit:

```
html {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
       -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
            box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

This will make the padding and width work more intuitively, or the way you would expect. My recommendation would be to add normalize and make sure it has the box-sizing: border-box reset, and then see how your width/height is working out for you. This might fix your problem outright.

But specifically to answer your question, the most likely reason is that if you want an element to be 216px with padding of 5px, you would set the width

```
element {
width: 206px; /* 216 - (5px padding + 5px padding) = 206px */
padding: 5px /* top: 5px, right: 5px, bottom: 5px, left: 5px; */
}
```

In summary, you need to add the padding (5px on the left and 5px on the right) to the overall width.

Answer (score 0):

If by "not working" you mean it's not set to 216x30, it's because you aren't taking into consideration padding and border width and height. It's working just fine.

When you set the height and width of an element, you set it on the content, not including margin, padding or borders.

[The CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)

Answer (score 0):

All of these attributes will mess with the height so you may want to split out the button and input styles and experiment with them until you get the perfect height:

```
padding: 15px 5px;
height: 30px; <-- not needed for the input
line-height: 30px;
font-size: 25px;
```

Here's a Fiddle to ref: https://jsfiddle.net/timhjellum/8mytme49/10/ if you are still having issues. Looks great in the Fiddle :-)